# Bash Script not executing command

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that is supposed to check for a running instance of a program and if its not running execute a command (echo for testing purposes). The problem is, that bash isn't executing the command even though it works when I copy/paste the command directly to the command line. I imagine my issue is simple and caused by my naivety with the script language.

The line in question:

```
ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep $SCRIPT > /dev/null || echo "`date` - $0 : $SCRIPT stopped. Restarting..."
```

If I paste it to the command line it works perfect, but when I run my script nothing happens. Suggestions?

EDIT: I believe I've resolved the issue. The script that is run to check the `queue_reader.sh` script I foolishly named `check_queue_reader.sh`" so the `ps -ef` command was finding itself preventing the `||` from executing.

Comment: Provide more of your code as context please.

Comment: Are you sure `$SCRIPT` is set to the same thing in the bash script and on the command line?

Comment: There's really not much more to it. I have a script that needs to be running and was going to drop this into a crontab job so it checks and restarts the process if needed. The only rest of my script right now are variables which won't provide any context to the situation.

Comment: @jwodder they are identical. I set SCRIPT to queue_reader.sh on the environment and within the script; it works on the command line but not the script. I made sure to confirm by doing an `echo $SCRIPT` and it shos up just fine.

Comment: This [section](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#How_can_I_check_to_see_if_my_game_server_is_still_running.3F__I.27ll_put_a_script_in_crontab.2C_and_if_it.27s_not_running.2C_I.27ll_restart_it...) from the Wooledge Bash wiki may be useful reading.

Comment: "Those who don't understand Unix are condemned to reinvent it, poorly" -- I really appreciate the link jw013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See edit on original post.

The script I was running was called "check_queue_reader.sh" and was using grep to search `ps -ef` for "queue_reader.sh". This caused the script to locate itself thus failing the check when it got to `||`